# How does weapon unlocking work? How do I quickly unlock the next weapon?

Tags: death-rally-2012

I'm currently getting parts to the Gatling Gun. How does unlocking a weapon work (what causes the weapon parts dropping)? And how can I quickly unlock the next weapon?

Any tips or tricks in getting those weapon parts to drop frequently?

- What types of races or tracks should I be looking for?
- How are weapon parts dropped?

  - Are there specific opponents/vehicles that are more likely to drop weapon parts?
  - Is it random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to unlock weapons (also vehicles and tracks) is to the pickup the parts found during a race.

Also, if you kill opponents during a race you will get parts too, so I'd center in killing opponents rather than wining races, knowing that you'll earn more money for killing them.

To unlock everything as fast as possible, go for *Beginner* level and the shortest/fastest tracks, which are [The Pit](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/DeathRally/leaderboards/46836), [Velodrama](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/DeathRally/leaderboards/46833) and [Oasis](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/DeathRally/leaderboards/46832) in that order.

Comment: What types of races or tracks should I be looking for? Are there specific opponents that are more likely to drop weapon parts?

Comment: Go for the 'Beginner' ones, harder ones have toughest opponents. I'm playing now and and for now all the opponents give parts when killed.

Comment: @galacticninja every kill gives you a new part

Comment: How are weapon parts dropped (aside from vehicle parts and other parts)? (Which vehicles drop which weapons?) Is it random? I'm asking because I'm looking to unlock the next weapon quickly.

Comment: The fastest way to get to the next weapon is to KILL KILL KILL! Every killed opponent will result in a dropped part. So run the tracks with the lowest challenge ratings listed (they will be the rightmost tracks in your options), and kill opponents. Then pick up the dropped bonus parts.

Comment: @galacticninja my conclusion is that it's random